# Find all files in a directory and its subdirectory

Tags: c++, file, directory

I would like to list all files in a given directory and its different subdirectory.
I found some code that I modified but it doing a never ending loop and I don't understand why.

```
int getdir (string dir, vector<string> &files)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    if((dp  = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL) {
        cout << "Error(" << errno << ") opening " << dir << endl;
        return errno;
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
        string test=dir+"/"+dirp->d_name;
        getdir(test,files);
    }
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

My main:

```
int main()
{
    string dir = string(".");
    vector<string> files = vector<string>();

    getdir(dir,files);

    for (unsigned int i = 0;i < files.size();i++) {
        cout << files[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: Any chance you have something like a symbolic link from a directory back to some parent of that directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely due to the "." directory entry returned as the first entry which represents the current directory.

This causes your algorithm to try to list the entries for ./. and then ././. endlessly repeating until your program would eventual crash when it ran out of memory.

There's also a ".." directory entry which represents the parent directory and can cause a similar recursive problem.

As noted by Jerry Coffin, symbolic links can also cause a very similar issue if you have links which point to a directory which is the parent or ancestor of the symbolic link.  This could be avoided with a much more complicated check or just simply excluding DT_LNK type entries all together.

Another issue is that you're trying to call getdir on files as well as subdirectories.

Try the following changes

```
while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
    string name(dir->d_name);
    if (name != "." && name != "..") {
        string test=dir+"/"+name;
        files.push_back(test);
        if (dir->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            getdir(test,files);
        }
    }
}
```